# Operator as a Variable in PHP

Tags: php, math

Im trying to compute a simple expression in PHP, the expression will always be the same the only change is in the operator.

Is there a simple solution to rather than duplicate the formula, just use the single expression and have the operator as a variable.

Something like..

```
function calc($qty, $qty_price, $max_qty, $operator_value, $operator = '-') 
{

  $operators = array(
   '+' => '+',
   '-' => '-',
   '*' => '*',
  );

  //adjust the qty if max is too large
  $fmq = ($max_qty > $qty)? $qty  : $max_qty ;


  return ( ($qty_price  . $operators[$operator] . $operator_value) * $fmq ) + ($qty - $fmq) * $qty_price;

}
```

Comment: You can use `eval()` but that's usually a bad code smell

Comment: It has crossed my mind but Id rather not use eval()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5.3 answer is nice, however, why not pre-calcaute $qty_price +-* $operator_value rather than repeating the whole function? It'd make the code a little more readable...

E.g.

```
function calc($qty, $qty_price, $max_qty, $operator_value, $operator = '-') 
{
  $qty_price_orig = $qty_price;

  switch($operator) {
      case '-':
         $qty_price -= $operator_value;
         break;
      case '+':
        $qty_price += $operator_value; 
        break;
      case '*':
         $qty_price = $qty_price * $operator_value; 
         break;


  //adjust the qty  i max is too large
  $fmq = ($max_qty > $qty)? $qty  : $max_qty ;


  return ( $qty_price * $fmq ) + ($qty - $fmq) * $qty_price_orig;

}
```

Comment: Ill probably use this code for compatibility reasons. My software needs to work on both PHP 5.1 and 5.3.

Comment: you might need to adjust your formula by the way - at the moment it is multiplying ($qty - $fmq) * $qty_price_orig and then adding ( $qty_price * $fmq ). If that is desired, add brackets around the multiplier so that when you come back to edit code / someone else comes into maintain it, it's immediately obvious what you wanted it to do.

Comment: do you mean  ( $qty_price * $fmq ) + ( ($qty - $fmq) * $qty_price_orig);

Comment: yup! Just means that it's immediately obvious to me what you meant the function to do. I wondered if you meant it to be ( ( $qty_price * $fmq ) + ($qty - $fmq) ) * $qty_price_orig; you see.

Answer (score 2):

If youre using 5.3+ then just use functions as your operator values:

```
$operators = array(
   '+' => function (a,b) { return a+b; },
   '-' => function (a,b) { return a-b; },
   '*' => function (a,b) { return a*b; },
);

$fmq = ($max_qty > $qty)? $qty  : $max_qty ;


return ( $operators[$operator]($qty_price, $operator_value) * $fmq ) + ($qty - $fmq) * $qty_price;
```

If youre using < 5.3 then you can use [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) to do much the same.

Comment: I didn't know we could store the function in the array, nice

Comment: I really like this solution, however I think in my case dealing with compatibility is probably more important so @stefancarlton solution may have to be the one for me

Comment: @IEnumerable: Yep, that requirement trumps ease/compactness. As long as you dont use `eval` youre good :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to get the job done:

```
<?php
$operators = array(
   '+' => '+',
   '-' => '-',
   '*' => '*',
  );

$a = 3;
$b = 4;
foreach ($operators as $op) {
    $expr = "$a ".$op." $b";
    eval("\$result=".$expr.";");
    print_r($expr." = ".$result."\n");
}
?>
```

However, use it with caution! Here is the official warning:

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Comment: I know you gave the warning, but eval is probably the least appropriate answer even though it works given how simple the problem is.